# Ekzercoj el "Paŝoj al plena posedo"

Tags: learning

Mi havas ekzemplero de "Paŝo al plena posedo" kaj legis la ekzercojn. Nun, mi serĉas la respondojn. Ĉu iu ajn havas la respondojn?

Answer (score 3):

Kopio de la solvoj por la ekzercoj de *Paŝoj al plena posedo* de William Auld [troviĝas tie](https://web.archive.org/web/20180312185753/http://eduinf.waw.pl/esp/lern/librejo/0032/0032.php).

Comment: Dankon, sed mi jam havas tiojn solvojn. Ili ekzistas ĉe la fino de la libro. Mi serĉas solvojn de la aliajn ekzercojn.